# missing relay candidates from TURN server

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, rfc5766turnserver

Just installed the coturn server (https://github.com/coturn/rfc5766-turn-server/). It looks like I'm getting only STUN candidates, but no TURN.
As a client I'm using node's webrtc-native.
I tried with public TURN server and did get 'relay' candidates, but I can't get any with my server.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is the configuration with which you are running, and how are you trying to generate TURN ICE candidates, show that, may be easier for us to debug...

Comment: The turn configuration is the default. On the client side I tested it in a couple of ways - one is with nodejs 'webrtc-native'. Just listening the 'onicecandidate' event. The other is just using online tool to test the server - like 'http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/'

Comment: but how do you pass the username and credential, you just start the TURN server by running `turnserver` ?

Comment: Initially yes, I just start the server and hopped to be able to get access as anonymous, as the doc says (here I wasn't sure what the 'username' and 'credentials' should be specified on the client, so I tried some). I also tried providing username and password with '-u' option and also with turnadmin... I didn't want to go with a database yet...

Comment: guessing that is the issue, credentials is kinda mandatory, just pass them as part of command like `-a -u test:test` also, are you passing the ssl cert files, probably they are also needed

Comment: still no relay candidates, just srflx... I've no any certificates. Wanted to try the simplest configuration possible.

Comment: @nchokoev did you manage to find an answer to this question?

Comment: I also can't generate the relay candidates, did everything I could...

Comment: @Alexander Did you find out what the problem is. I also don't see relay candidates.

Comment: @OliverHausler did you solve the problem ? Same happened to my setup. Thanks.

Comment: @ozgurozkanakdemirci We solved the problem. I am trying to recall the exact reason. It was not related to coturn, but rather the underlying Linux system. One problem was that ports under 1024 require sudo permissions, the other problem was similar, but I don't remember precisely. What I can tell you is that outgoing UDP packets were blocked at the firewall or dropped when leaving the node. They were created by coturn and then dropped by the OS, so the client wouldn't see the relay candidates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide realm in your TURN server configuration.
Firefox uses an empty realm if it can't find one. But chrome and firefox don't use any default realm and they will fail to authenticate.
Check my complete stack overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120698/webrtc-missing-relay-candidates-in-firefox/72377353#72377353)